# Stuck light switch

Tags: wiring

My light switch is stuck in the off position. What has caused this and is it dangerous? We haven't been doing any electrical work. It seems to have gotten stuck by itself.

Comment: Not dangerous. Replace it.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not dangerous but it does sound broke.

You will need to get it replaced or do it youself.

Always make sure the power is off first.

Good luck!

Comment: +1 As to what has caused it, switches are fairly cheap plastic and metal contraptions that go through thousands of cycles, often with a *snap*. That they last as long as they do (usually) is a small miracle.

Answer (score 0):

It happens.  Contractor grade switches cost literally a dollar.  That says a lot about why they fail.

If you want quality switches, they make them in the $5 price range.

The same is true of receptacles.